# Finding limit $\sin (1/x)$ on $(0,1]$ as $x$ tends to $0^+$?

Tags: limits

limit $\sin (1/x)$ on $(0,1]$ as $x$ tends to $0^+$:
I have substituted for $x$ and found that it does not exist because it will be $sin \infty$, am I correct?

Comment: You could say the limit is $\sin\infty$ only if 1) the sine function is defined at $\infty$ and 2) it is continuous there.

Answer (score 2):

The limit does indeed not exist, but here's a better way of explaining why. The sequence $x_n=\frac{1}{2n\pi+\pi/2}$ obtains $\sin x_n=1$, while the sequence $x_n=\frac{1}{2n\pi-\pi/2}$ obtains $\sin x_n=-1$, Thus no limit $L$ is approached by $\sin\frac{1}{x}$ for all sufficiently small $x>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

Let's exhibit two sequence that converges to $0$ but the corresponding function values evaluated at those sequences are not take the same value.

Consider $x_n = \frac1{2\pi n},$ and observe what is $\sin(x_n)$.

Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sin(x_n)$.

Do the same thing to  $y_n = \frac1{(2n+\frac12)\pi}$.

Comment: oops, I made a mistake, thanks.